# After video convert to hls with ffmpeg, new video has no screen and has just audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am having problems with HLS stream creation, sometimes my created video just has audio and it's display a black screen
Here is my code in below

```
/opt/nodejs/ffmpeg -i "https://******-v1-post-content.s3.us-east-
2.amazonaws.com/104/posts/win/video/item-1615842876280.mov" -codec: copy -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls /tmp/item-1615842876280.m3u8
```

The Output Of command

```
stderr: ffmpeg version 4.2.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://*****-v1-post-content.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/104/posts/win/video/item-1615842876280.mov:
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-03-13T08:49:02.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:03.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7984 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 7881 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2021-03-13T08:49:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-13T08:49:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
[hls @ 0x6684ec0] Opening '/tmp/item-16158428762800.ts' for writing
Output #0, hls, to '/tmp/item-1615842876280.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 7881 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2021-03-13T08:49:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-13T08:49:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
```

Thank you!

Sevada

Comment: What player are you using? Is the output in your question from a working or not working HLS stream creation? 4.2 is old. Try again using a [recent version from git master](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), not release.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We are using AVPlayer.

Comment: This might be because you are not copying the video stream to your output m3u8. Try to mention the video stream explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue too. It seems to occur frequently when trying to copy HEVC videos with the '-codec: copy' command.

One workaround I've found is to only copy the audio stream and transcode the video stream by replacing '-codec: copy' with '-codec:a copy'. Although it can be more time-consuming and resource-intensive, this method works.

I'm not an expert on FFmpeg, so it would be great if someone could offer a detailed explanation of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this issue today, but my video seems to be encoded with AV1. The HLS only have the audio stream, no video. But I tried to convert to DASH and it worked, there both audio and video stream. It seems that there are  problems with HLS when converted from AV1 and HEVC. Hope someone can help with this problems instead of not using -c:v copy and re-encode the whole video, my app can't allow such delay for encoding.